# Form AJAX post response cycle in Laravel 4.1.*

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a rather old site that I have inherited as part of a new position - it's been built to Laravel 4.1.* version specs.

My issue is `Response::json` returning undefined variables in the response, using standard AJAX post method with all CSRF stuff and ajaxSetup() defined correctly.

**application.blade.php**

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST', //This will always be a post method for the supplier chain check form.
   url: 'supply-us/application', //URL endpoint for the post form method: we'll set this to the controller function we're targeting.
   data: { 'companyName': values['companyName'] }, //This will carry the form data that is needed to be passed to the server.
   success: function (response) {
       console.log(response['companyName']); << THIS LINE RETURNS "undefined"

       console.log(typeof response) << THIS LINE RETURNS string
   },
   error: function (response) {
       console.log(response);
   },
 });
```

values['companyName'] returns what I input into the form. The above "response" simple chucks back html - so I think my routes might be incorrectly defined or incorrectly defined in the AJAX url param, perhaps? Here are the two applicable routes:

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('supply-us/application', 'ApplicationController');
Route::post('supply-us/application', 'ApplicationController@processSupplierApplication');
```

**ApplicationController.php**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApplicationController extends FrontController {
  public function getSupplierApplication() {
         return self::getPage('supply-us/application');
    }

  public function processSupplierApplication(Request $request) {
    if (Input::has('companyName')) {

       $this->companyName = Input::get('companyName');

       $data = [
          'success': true,
          'companyName': $this->companyName
       ];

       return response()->json($data);

    }

  }

}
```

Any pro-tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you get after `console.log(response);` inside ajax success

Comment: @michael try this   console.log(response.companyName);

Comment: @bipin I tried that first - still undefined...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts try like this  for eg :-$app="error";
     return response()->json($app); then in you console.log(response.companyName);

Comment: console.log(response.companyName);  you are returning json

Comment: try converting your string to an object: var obj = JSON.parse(response); console.log(obj.companyName);

Comment: @Maraboc is this exists in you class $public companyName its seem like something missing in you controller, check storage/log/laravel.php what error you are getting there

Comment: Hi - so looks like the response is coming back in the error function for AJAX callback... (this is with the return response()-> method outlined by @bipin)

Comment: @bipin I've made a few changes to my controller response - so passing in a data array.

Comment: @bipin I'm missing $request->input() aren't I?

Comment: I find it amazing that no one can give me a straight answer for a method for posting form data with Laravel!!! What a crummy framework.

Answer (score -1):

to check what your are missing in controller when posting or getting your result 
usually which i follow

1. in blade.php

   ```
   <.form method="post" action="{{url('supply-us/application')}}".>
     {{csrf_field()}}
     <.input type="text" name="companyName".>
     <./form.>
   ```

remove dot try this it will help you to find missing thing in controller

in your blade

```
<.input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName".>
```

in your ajax

```
 var company =  $('#companyName').val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'supply-us/application', 
      data: { 'Company':company,'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'  }, 
  success: function (response) {
    alert(data) // if this not work then try this alert(data.company)

  },
  error: function (response) {
   console.log(response);
 },
});
```

in your controller

`<?php
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

 class ApplicationController extends FrontController {
  public function getSupplierApplication() {
      return self::getPage('supply-us/application');
  }

 public function processSupplierApplication(Request $req) {
     if (!$req->get('Company')==null) {
      $company = $req->get('Company');
   return response()->json($company);
  }else{
    $company="no input give";
   return response()->json($company);
   }
}`

}

Comment: Hi Bipin - hmmm, ok - so I'm using a preventDefault with my AJAX submission so I'd rather not go down this line. It's a responsive form. I'm doing all of the csrf stuff. The issue is that the data that is coming back is coming back undefined. I just want to know how to accept the data within the post controller@function and then process that data then submit data back to the view. It really shouldn't be this complex imho. I can do this with Django no problem at all. Why is Laravel such a pain??

Comment: @MichaelRoberts updated answer please check hope this will help you

Comment: @MichaelRoberts actually it too simple you just need to get familiar with this

Comment: So many issues with your answer I don't know where to begin. Firstly, data is not defined. So is it response.companyName?

Comment: alert(response.CompanyName) comes back as undefined.

Comment: If it helps - the response is just coming back as the html of the page itself...this really isn't helping.

Comment: I'm still getting undefined on alert(response.companyName) ... I've used request method but surely it needs to be passed to an array??

Comment: @MichaelRoberts sorry my mistake check answer again

Comment: !!!!! data is not defined. You're clearly not understanding this at all?

Comment: `console.log(response)` is coming back with the current page's html dump??

Comment: @MichaelRoberts what you are getting in this console.log(response.company) and change below line of code i had modified it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164257/discussion-between-michael-roberts-and-bipin).